# How to create a HKAnchoredObjectQuery in descending order with limit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, healthkit

In one of our project. I have to fetch the Health kit data like past 30 days.

We are using the HKAnchoredObjectQuery to fetch the Historical data. At first time If we try to fetch it will return a huge data. So our API couldn't handled that much amount of data. So we have using the limit in the query, but now the problem is it is returning in ascending order but we actually want always most recent data. Is there anyway to fetch the Health data by using HKAnchoredObjectQuery with limit in descending order.

Currently we are fetching like this

```
    HKAnchoredObjectQuery *anchoredQuery = [[HKAnchoredObjectQuery alloc] initWithType:quantityType predicate:predicate anchor:anchor limit:1 resultsHandler:handler];

    [healthStore executeQuery:anchoredQuery];
```

Note: This can be achieved by setting up local database. But we don't want to duplicate the same data

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`HKAnchoredObjectQuery` does not support sort order by design. Querying by "anchor" requires HealthKit to sort the results by anchor. If you want to use a sort order, you must use `HKSampleQuery` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are in async context:

```
let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
let query = HKSampleQueryDescriptor(
            predicates: [.workout()],
            sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.endDate, order: .reverse)],
            limit: 10
        )
        
let result = try await query.result(for: healthStore)
```